# Renaming nested lists with lapply

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply, nested-lists

I have a nested list:

```
my_list <- list(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)

my_nested_list <- list(D = my_list, E = my_list, F = my_list)
```

I want to change the names of the inner most elements to the following:

```
my_names <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
```

So, A, B, C should becoming X, Y, Z.

Here is my attempt:

```
name_changer <- lapply(my_nested_list, FUN = function(x){
  lapply(x, FUN = function(y){
    names(y) <- my_names
  })
})
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setNames` as well -

```
lapply(my_nested_list, setNames, my_names)

#$D
#$D$X
#[1] 1

#$D$Y
#[1] 2

#$D$Z
#[1] 3

#$E
#$E$X
#[1] 1

#$E$Y
#[1] 2

#$E$Z
#[1] 3

#$F
#$F$X
#[1] 1

#$F$Y
#[1] 2

#$F$Z
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have two `lapply` loops when you only need one.

Your original second loop tries to apply the 3-element "my_names" vector to each individual element of "my_list", which won't work, since the lengths don't match. But you don't need the second loop at all:

```
my_list <- list(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)
my_nested_list <- list(D = my_list, E = my_list, F = my_list)
my_names <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

name_changer <- lapply(my_nested_list, FUN = function(x){
  names(x) <- my_names
  return(x)
})

str(name_changer)
List of 3
 $ D:List of 3
  ..$ X: num 1
  ..$ Y: num 2
  ..$ Z: num 3
 $ E:List of 3
  ..$ X: num 1
  ..$ Y: num 2
  ..$ Z: num 3
 $ F:List of 3
  ..$ X: num 1
  ..$ Y: num 2
  ..$ Z: num 3
```